# Show list depending on search results angular

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I based this on the [Hero-Search](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6) from the tour of heroes Tutorial. There you can search for heroes which returns a [list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fHCt.jpg) that only shows the results containing the letters and let's you click on the hero you want.

I want to modify this so that my current [list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mSFl.jpg) is filtered by what is typed into the search box.

This is what you see on the picture:

```
<h1><span id="monstersTitle">Monsters</span></h1>
<app-monster-search></app-monster-search>
<ul class="monsters">
 <li *ngFor="let monster of monsters">
  <span class="badge" (click)="addToEncounter(monster)">{{monster.name}} 
  </span> Hitpoints: {{monster.hitPoints}} Armor: {{monster.armor}}
 </li>
</ul>
```

And I tried moving it to the app-monster-search component:

```
<div id="search-component">
<h4>Monster Search</h4>

<input #searchBox id="search-box" (keyup)="search(searchBox.value)" />
<ul class="monsters">
 <li *ngFor="let monster of monsters$ | async">">
  <span class="badge" (click)="addToEncounter(monster)">{{monster.name}} 
   </span> Hitpoints: {{monster.hitPoints}} Armor: {{monster.armor}}
 </li>
</ul>

export class MonsterSearchComponent implements OnInit {
monsters$: Observable<Monster[]>;
private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

constructor(private monsterService: MonsterService, private sharedService: 
SharedMonsterService) {}

// Push a search term into the observable stream.
search(term: string): void {
 this.searchTerms.next(term);
}

getMonsters(): void{
 this.monsterService.getMonsters()
  .subscribe(monster => this.monsters$ = monster); //error on "this.monsters$" = Type 'Monster[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Monster[]>
}

addToEncounter(monster){
 this.sharedService.publishMonster(monster);
}
```

The problem here is that the this.monsters$ is of type Observable and I need a type of monster there to be able to subscribe. Or is there an other/easier way to achieve this?

Monster Service:

```
public getMonsters(): Observable<Monster[]>{
return this.http.get<Monster[]>(this.monsterUrl).pipe(
  tap(heroes => this.log(`fetched heroes`)),
  catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
);
}

searchMonsters(term: string): Observable<Monster[]> {
if (!term.trim()) {
  // if not search term, return empty hero array.
  return of([]);
}
return this.http.get<Monster[]>(`${this.monsterUrl}/?name=${term}`).pipe(
  tap(_ => this.log(`found monsters matching "${term}"`)),
  catchError(this.handleError<Monster[]>('searchMonsters', []))
);
```

}

**Edit:**

For future reference, if others are looking for something similar:

```
<div id="search-component">
<h4>Monster Search</h4>

<input #searchBox id="search-box" (keyup)="search(searchBox.value)"/>
<ul class="monsters">
<li *ngFor="let monster of (monsters$ | async)">
  <span class="badge" (click)="addToEncounter(monster)">{{monster.name}} 
 </span> Hitpoints: {{monster.hitPoints}}
  Armor: {{monster.armor}}
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
<div *ngIf="!searchBox.value">
 <ul class="monsters">
 <li *ngFor="let monster of (monsters)">
  <span class="badge" (click)="addToEncounter(monster)">{{monster.name}} 
  </span> Hitpoints: {{monster.hitPoints}}
  Armor: {{monster.armor}}
 </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `monsters$: Observable<Monster[]>` means `this.monsters$ ` is an `Observable` of type Monster Array what do mean by *The problem here is that the this.monsters$ is of type Observable and I need a type of monster there to be able to subscribe*

Comment: `<li *ngFor="let monster of (monsters$ | async)">` try it

Comment: the error says: Type 'Monster[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Monster[]>'

Comment: If this does not work kindly provide a working stackblitz

Comment: Share your service code

Comment: I edited my original post with the service code

Comment: try and see if this works HTML `<li *ngFor="let monster of monsters)">` and Component `monsters: Array<Monster>=[]`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-monster-search I put all the code in the stackblitz. The issue lies in the monster-search component. I tried what you said here above but then the this.monsters$ in OnInit breaks.

Comment: Could you provide a working stackblitz ? Current one misses couple of files

Comment: Sorry, the routing module didn't want to work on stackblitz. But yatharth varshney was able to help me out ! Thank you for your time @Vikas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is self explanatory in itself, just change "*getMonsters()*" method as shown below :-

```
getMonsters(): void{
 this.monsters$ = this.monsterService.getMonsters();
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. Now the only problem I still have is that when the page is loaded, there is no list yet. I'd like the list to be there when the page is loaded, but it has to dissappear depending on the value in the searchbox?

Comment: Perhaps not my day I can't believe I missed this :(

Comment: call getMonsters() on ngOnInit of component.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have one list with monsters probably downloaded once when component initializes you don't need Observable stream for monsters because this list doesn't change when you type something. Only async thing here is user input and for this you could create new stream:

```
this.filtredMonsters$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
  map(searchTerms => this.monsters.filter(monster => monster.name.startsWith(searchTerms)))
```

and then change ngFor loop to use filtredMonsters$:

```
<li *ngFor="let monster of filtredMonsters$ | async">
```

But remeber to create that stream only when list of monsters is available.

Answer (score 0):

and if your MonsterService has method searchMonsters you can also use it to get filtredMonsters$ but replace map operator by switchMap:

```
this.filtredMonsters$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
  switchMap(searchTerms => this.monsterService.searchMonsters(searchTerms)));
```